# Geometric/Algebraic intersection numbers of curves on surfaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, curves-and-surfaces

I have the following problem, and struggling to find some references.

Suppose I start with a homology class of a curve on a closed genus $g$ surface $$h=(a_{1},b_{1},\dots,a_{g},b_{g})\in H_{1}(\Sigma_{g};\mathbb{Z}).$$
If $h$ is primitive, I can find a simple closed curve $\gamma$ such that $[\gamma] = h$. Now I want to find another disjoint simple closed curve $\gamma'$ so that $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ don't intersect. We have that $[\gamma'] = (a_{1}',b_{1}',\dots,a_{g}',b_{g}')\in H_{1}(\Sigma_{g};\mathbb{Z})$ for some $a_{i}',b_{i}'\in\mathbb{Z}$.

What restrictions can we place on the $a_{i}'$ and $b_{i}'$ to ensure that $\gamma'$ is disjoint from $\gamma$?

Clearly we would require that we have for the algebraic intersection number $\hat{i}([\gamma],[\gamma'])=0$, but it seems that the algebraic intersection number is not easily computable. I think I found the apocryphal formula
$$\hat{i}((a_{1},b_{1},\dots,a_{g},b_{g}),(a'_{1},b'_{1},\dots,a'_{g},b'_{g})) = \sum_{i=1}^{g} a_{i}b'_{i}-a'_{i}b_{i},$$
but can't find a proof.

Any references, advice, or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are $a_i$ and $b_i$ in terms of the geometry of the surface? The proof at the level of detail you're requesting seems to hinge entirely on the particular choice of basis of homology.

Comment: The formula you mention is correct. The algebraic intersection number is a symplectic form on $H_1(\Sigma_g)$ which takes on exactly the form you suggest. See Farb and Margalit's *A Primer on Mapping Class Groups*, chapter 6.

Of course, asking for algebraic intersection $0$ is not nearly enough to have geometric intersection $0$.

Comment: @EthanDlugie, is there an obvious counterexample I could think about of a homology class $[\gamma']$ where $\hat{i}([\gamma],[\gamma'])=0$, but $[\gamma']$ does not contain a representative that has zero geometric intersection number with $\gamma$?

Comment: Let $a_i,b_i,$ be the standard geometric basis for the first homology of $\Sigma_3$ (see F&M, p. 165). Let $\gamma$ be $b_2$ and let $\gamma'$ be the simple closed curve which wraps around the 1st and 3rd holes and "under" the second. As as a homology class, this is $a_1+a_3$. Then $\hat i(\gamma,\gamma')=0$ but $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ intersect twice without any bigons, so these intersections are essential.

Comment: Awesome, thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Collecting my previous comments here. The formula you give for the algebraic intersection number is correct, and points to the fact that the intersection number is a symplectic form on $H_1(\Sigma_g)$ (with $\mathbb{R}$-coefficients if you want to make it a vector space). A reference for this is Farb and Margalit's *A Primer on Mapping Class Groups*, Chapter 6.

You said that algebraic intersection number zero is necessary for geometric intersection number zero, which is certainly true. However it is not sufficient. Just take this example on the genus 3 surface (or any higher genus):

[image]

The trouble is that specifying a homology class fails to really specify a homotopy class of simple closed curve. For instance if you chose $\gamma'$ to go above rather than below the middle hole in this picture, you'd have a homologous curve which is now disjoint from $\gamma$.

However in the genus $\leq 2$ case, I believe $\hat i=0$ does imply $i=0$ for simple closed curves representing primitive homology classes. This is easy on the torus, since simple closed curves here in minimal position intersect with the same orientation at all points. I haven't been able to come up with a proof yet in the genus two case beyond lack of counterexample.

**Edit:** @AndyPutman observed that I was wrong in the genus 2 case. Taking sufficiently complicated pseudo-Anosov elements in the Torelli group lets you construct curves which intersect very highly but do so in an algebraically trivial manner.

Comment: I just came upon this post.  Your final paragraph is false in genus 2.  Here's a counterexample: https://imgur.com/a/BTWc0wB

Comment: @AndyPutman I spy a bigon between those two curves!

Comment: Whoops, that's embarrassing!  Here's another one that (hopefully) works: https://imgur.com/a/I4igvY3

Comment: By the way, here's how I know without drawing a picture that this must be false.  If $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve and $f$ is a pseudo-Anosov that lies in the Torelli group, then for large $n$ the curves $f^n(\gamma)$ and $\gamma$ will intersect many times but be homologous, and hence have algebraic intersection number $0$.  And starting in genus $2$ the Torelli group will contain many pseudo-Anosov elements (just think of your favorite construction of pseudo-Anosovs using Dehn twists, and do it with separating twists).

Comment: And I've just realized from your example that you could do something even easier: take a separating (hence nullhomologous) curve and then some curve that intersects it nontrivially.